# Parsing a message notification index in python using regular expressions

Tags: python, regex

I need a regular expression to parse a message notification which I get when I receive a message on a GSM modem connected to my laptop via a serial port.

The general format is as follows:

```
+CMTI: "SM",0
```

Here 0 is the index number of the message that is stored on the SIM card and mat take any numeric value.

What I'm using right now is:

```
regex = re.compile("\+CMTI: \"SM\",\d")
```

What should I use instead?

**UPDATE:** 
Here's the code I'm using right now:

```
def poll(x):
    regex = re.compile("\+CMTI: \"SM\",\d+")
    lst = []
    for l in x:
        for m in [regex.search(l)]:
            if m:
                lst.append(m)
                print "You have received a new message!"
```

How can I implement re.match here instead?

**ANOTHER UPDATE:**
    I've modified the code based on all the answers here. Yet, it still doesn't seem to work.

```
def poll(x):
    regex = re.compile(r'\+CMTI: "SM",(\d+)')
    lst = []
    for l in x:
        for m in [regex.search(l)]:
            if m:
                lst.append(m)
                print "You have received a new message!"
```

Comment: what gets sent into poll()? a single line/AT response? Multiple lines?

Comment: Multiple lines of AT respose, the entire code is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15568281/polling-for-new-messages-received-by-a-gsm-modem-using-python

Comment: @FredrikHåård here's an example of a response:

    AT+CREG? #AT command

    +CREG: 0,1 #Response

    OK #status report

Comment: I've updated my question again

Comment: "for m in [regex.search(l)]:" is unnecessary. Also, m is a match object, not a string; as best I can guess what you're looking for is something like "for line in x: m=regex.search(line); if m: lst.append(m.group(1)); print('You have...')". You really should read up on http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\d will only capture a single digit. Are you interested in the index itself? In that case you need to add a capture group so you can extract it, e.g.

```
>>> re.match(r'\+CMTI: "SM",(\d+)', '+CMTI: "SM",0').group(1)
'0'
>>> re.match(r'\+CMTI: "SM",(\d+)', '+CMTI: "SM",234566').group(1)
'234566'
```

With a compiled regex it becomes:

```
>>> regex = re.compile(r'\+CMTI: "SM",(\d+)')
>>> regex.match('+CMTI: "SM",0').group(1)
'0'
```

A complete example from your code that appends message IDs to the list 'lst' would be

```
def poll(x):
    regex = re.compile(r'\+CMTI: "SM",(\d+)')
    lst = []
    for line in x:
        match = regex.search(line):
        if match:
            lst.append(match.group(1))
            print "You have received a new message!"
```

Comment: why is the '+CMTI: "SM",0' used after the comma?

Comment: It's just the string I'm matching against, since I don't compile the regex (for brevity). Using a compiled regex you would just use regex.match(mystring).

Comment: cool :) could you take a look at the update in my question :)

Answer (score 0):

Your regex works fine for me. One thing I'd change would be to add a `+` after `\d`:

```
re.match(r'\+CMTI: \"SM\",\d+', '+CMTI: "SM",0')
```

Comment: why is the '+CMTI: "SM",0' used after the comma?

Answer (score 0):

If you want receive 0 from string you can try: 
'+CMTI: "SM",(\d)'